# Finding target's id when its parent generates event in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Here I'm trying to get the id of the target in `showMe()`. For example, when I click button or image panel's `showMe()` function executes first. Here I want to capture the button/image's id.

```
private function init():void
            {
                pnl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,showMe);
            }

            private function showMe(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Hello");
            }

    <s:Panel id="pnl" height="400" width="700" creationComplete="init()">
                <s:Button id="btn1" label="showParents"/>
                <mx:Image id="img1" source="markupIndicator.png"  buttonMode="true"/>

    </s:Panel>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very clear why you need to catch panel's `mouseDown` and try to get inner control's ids but you can change your code this way:

```
private function init():void
            {
                pnl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,showMe);
            }

            private function showMe(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Hello " + eve.currentTarget.id);
            }

            private function showMyID(eve:MouseEvent):void
            {
                showMe(eve);
            }

    <s:Panel id="pnl" height="400" width="700" >
                <s:Button id="btn1" label="showParents" click="showMyID(event)"/>
                <mx:Image id="img1" source="markupIndicator.png" click="showMyID(event)" buttonMode="true"/>

    </s:Panel>
```

Comment: Hi @Constantiner, eve.currentTarget is panel. So, I'm getting panel's id.

Comment: You are right. Even I wanted to listen pane's click. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think that should work:

```
private function init():void
    {
        pn1background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,showMe);
            btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,showMe);
            img1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,showMe);
    }

    private function showMe(eve:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(eve.currentTarget.id);
    }

    <s:Panel id="pnl" height="400" width="700" >
                <s:Button id="btn1" label="showParents"/>
                <mx:Image id="img1" source="markupIndicator.png"  buttonMode="true"/>
                <s:Panel id="pn1background" height="400" width="700" / >
    </s:Panel>
```

Comment: I wrote "event" instead of "eve" (as in your code). Try again with the updated example?

Comment: Hi @Laurent, eve.currentTarget indicates panel and its giving panel's id.

Comment: This is strange, do you also have an `click` event handler on the panel? Otherwise, try `eve.target.id` but that probably won't work.

Comment: Yeah @Laurent, there mouseDown event listener is there on panel. I want to capture the target(button/image)'s ID in that function.

Comment: Oh ok I see it now. You need to remove the mouseDown event listener from the panel. If you want to capture mouseDown events when the user click on the background, add a background to the panel (below the button and label components) and add the event listener to this background.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full code to show what I mean about the background.